# cv2 video capture to image frame

Tags: python, opencv

Hey there I am trying to make License plate number recognition and I am having a problem converting cv2 video capture to a image so the program can detect a plate

Here is my code :

```
def getLicensePlateNumber(image):

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while camera.isOpened():
    value, frame = camera.read()
    image = cv2.imread(frame)
    cv2.imshow('Camera', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am receiving this error:

```
    image = cv2.imread(frame)
TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'numpy.ndarray' to 'str' for 'filename'
```

The code works perfectly for image files

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is this a question? I don't see what your asking.

Comment: Hey thanks for the replay I forgot to write the error , please look at the edit 
Thank you

Comment: What do you want? the 'image' variable is already bgr matrix which represents a frame image.

Answer (score 1):

`imread` reads those images which images are saved in your pc. You have to send a path location where image is saved as a parameter to `imread`.